# How to get current variable from excel into SPSS

Tags: spss

I'm new in the SPSS and I need some help.I have a Excel file with many columns and I have to write syntax to get only the variables which I need (for example id name). The name of the variables are at first row.

Comment: How is this related to programming? Please, consider switching to [superuser](http://superuser.com/) on this one.

Answer (score 0):

First import your excel file (use the open data menu and paste the syntax).
then use this:

```
add files /file=* /keep= var1 var2 var3.
```

This will let you keep only the variables you need and in the preferred order.
if some of these variables are ordered consecutively in the file you can use `"someVar TO someotherVar"` in the `keep` subcommand.